# How to simulate exponential growth

Tags: java

I'm working on a game, and in it I want growth to happen exponentially - so, for example, getting from 2 to 3 people might take around the same time as getting from 2 million to 3 million people. However, I would like this growth to be random if possible to make it more realistic. So far I have a method that works well:

```
if (buildingCount > populationCount && foodCount > populationCount)
    for(int i=1;i<populationCount;i++) {
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(1000);
        if (randomInt == 42) {
            Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount+1);
        }
    }
if ((buildingCount < populationCount || foodCount < populationCount)&&populationCount>2)
    for(int i=1;i<populationCount;i++) {
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(1000);
        if (randomInt == 888) {
            Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount-1);
        }
```

However, I realise this will not be sustainable. It runs approximately 60 times a second (on that magnitude), and once it reaches levels of millions, it may end up running billions of operations per second - a bit much for such a simple check. I'll put it on an interval if I have to, but I'd rather keep it random.

I tried to find an equation for the probability but ended up with:

[Σ(99^r/1000^(r+1)) from r=0 to p (where p = probability)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+series&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22999%5Ex%2F1000%5E(x%2B1)%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22Sum%22,+%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D+-%3E%221000%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22sum+of+series%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D)

Is there any easy way to change that probability to a test, or a simpler method in Java to accomplish such a purpose.

If it helps I'm using LibGdx as an engine.

Comment: Rather than looping N times for your population and incrementing by one, why not pick a number from 1 to 1000 and multiply by N?

Comment: Do you mean pick a number, 42 for example, and multiply that by the population - eg. 3.  That would give 126 - too big an increase, or do you mean there's a 1 in 1000 chance of increasing by 3 - in which case it would miss out populations of 4 and 5

Comment: If the building and food conditions are met, the split (population++) chance for each person is 1/1000. So for N people, there will be on average n/1000 splits per tick. Why not just add (n +- random)/1000 people per tick? The random would have to be a normal distribution based on n. Even with 20 people you will rarely get random=1500, for +2 pop on a tick, but normally it would +0 or +1. Might need a bit of tweaking for the initial stage of the game when pop is small (so as to not always round to zero), but should work nicely after that.

Comment: @leoderprofi Good point, BigInteger could be a solution however its immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that, assuming the distribution of random numbers is uniform, you'll increase the population count by `n / 1000`, on average, for a population count of `n`.

To emulate this, it might be a good idea to just divide `populationCount` by `500` and use [`ThreadLocalRandom#nextGaussian`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextGaussian--) to determine how much to increment `populationCount` by, allowing you to rid yourself of the for-loop:

```
if (buildingCount > populationCount && foodCount > populationCount) {
    if (populationCount > 1000) {
        int randomNum = (int) ((ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextGaussian() / 2 + 0.5) * populationCount / 500);

        Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount + randomNum);
    } else {
        // Original for-loop here for populations less than 1000.
    }
}
```

For a population of `10,000`, this would increase the population by an average of `10` (ranges from `0` to `20` in this case, but favors a mean of `10` due to the use of `nextGaussian`).

Comment: Beat me to using Gaussian distributions. I think this is the best answer since it maintains the randomness that OP wants rather than a constant growth.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit formula for exponential growth is:
x_t=x_0*(1+r)^t
where t is your interval (in your case there are 60 intervals per second)
and r is your growth rate. So the formula for the increase in one interval is:

x_1=x_0*(1+r)

with x_0 being the previous population.

So basically, instead of looping over your whole population count on every interval, you can just this (with a growth rate of 0.1%):

```
Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount + Math.floor(populationCount * 0.001f));
```

For population decrease just subtract instead of adding.

```
Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount - Math.floor(populationCount * 0.001f));
```

In order to integrate randomness you could do something like this:

```
Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount + Math.floor(populationCount * 0.001f * random.nextFloat()));
```

That way your growth rate would fluctuate between 0% and 100% on each increment.

Then it would only be a matter of experimenting with the growth rate.

This strategy should only be employed though as soon as the population exceeds about 5 * (1 / growth rate), for otherwise Math.floor will render it too inaccurate or even diminish any growth.

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you are doing is : for every person it has a chance of 1 over 1000 to produce a new person. Your code is going crazy on big numbers cause you check everyone.

For big numbers your algorithm is equivalent as multiplying your population by 1.001 (1+1/1000). The random aspect will disappear for big numbers (as explain [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers))

But for small number the random is really important. I think the best way to handle this is to define a population level over which you use a multiplication and under which you use your method.

```
if (buildingCount > populationCount && foodCount > populationCount)
    if(populationCount > 10000) { //I use 10000 has population level but do what you want
        for(int i=1;i<populationCount;i++) {
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(1000);
            if (randomInt == 42) {
                Data.main.setPopulationCount(populationCount+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here

with your exemple 2-3   2M to 3M
i would say  use a *1.5 operator

exemple: 
every 60S  --> people=people*1.5

pearps i'am don't understand clearly your need

lio

Comment: But I want it to increase slowly and in increments, so you may see the numbers increase faster, but until maybe 1000, you will still see the population value increase. In that method, it will go: 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 9 -> 13 ect. And either way that's too fast - the check occurs every 1/60 seconds - not every 60 seconds